# Why do we ignore C in definite integrals?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I am teaching myself Calc, and I could not find a reason that we ignore the constant of integration when we evaluate a definite integral. Thanks.

P.S, my etiquette is not that good when relating to calc, as I am only in 8th grade. Thank you for help.

Comment: Because C- C= 0!  For example, $\int 6xdx= 3x^2+ C$ so $\int_a^b 6x dx= \left[3x^2+ C\right]_a^b= (3b^2+ C)- (3a^2+ C)= (3b^2- 3a^2)+ (C- C)= 3(b^2- a^2)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $F(x)$ is an antiderivative of $f(x)$. Then for any other antiderivative $G(x)$ of $f(x)$, we have $G(x)=F(x)+c$ for a constant $c$. The definite integral of $f(x)$ over an interval evaluates to
$$\int_a^bf(x)dx=F(b)-F(a)$$
But also
$$\int_a^bf(x)dx=G(b)-G(a)=(F(b)+c)-(F(a)+c)=F(b)-F(a),$$
(provided both sides exist), so we can see that the constant cancels out. So it doesn't matter what arbitrary constant we choose, in the end the definite integral will have the same value, so we just take *any* choice of antiderivative, ignore the arbitrary constant, and call it a day.